# How to align an image in a table towards the right side of a row or something?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I tried to create a newsletter, for that I heard that we should use table instead of div so that there won't be any design issues.

So what I tried here is a logo should be right most side, I tried to use the rowspan may be I'm using it in a wrong manner, I don't know.

It should become like:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1 style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; color: #444444 !important; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                   Newsletter
                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3 style=
                    "color: #444444 !important; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: 2px; font-size: 18px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 8px;">
                  small tagline for newsletter</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <img alt="news" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjKPW.jpg" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Zhg/)**

How to bring the image to the right side as in the above figure. I used **border** for reference purpose. we'll remove it once the image brought to the right side.

Comment: Learn basic table layouts first. <tr> creates a new row. <td> is a new column.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani He is creating a news letter, table is a better thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use [`rowspan`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/rowspan) and not <s>`colspan`</s>

```
<td rowspan="2">
     <img alt="news" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjKPW.jpg" />
</td>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/r5Zhg/9/)

Comment: Blap blap, you kicked NoobEditors ass on this one ;) +1

Comment: @Deekey ... he's not that awesome ;)

Comment: @Ruddy : lol...though i enjoyed your comment...but refrain from such language on community posts...its not fb chat!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor LOL it's fine... we don't take it too seriously -Ruddy hehe thank you

Comment: Thanks. I also tried rowspan but i didn't get this desing. Is it to do with order of the markup also? @Mr. Alien

Comment: @rram no, just take my code and review it, you will get it what I did there

Comment: @NoobEditor `ass` isn't bad language. It means donkey. And `blap blap` is just a noise (The best noise). So not sure what you mean on that one. :D

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong. i don't have much knowledge compared to you. What i thought is we are developing newsletter with table for consistent design in all circumference so why should we use styling with the default behaviour of the table. As we use table to avoid design issues in some circumference. @NoobEditor

Comment: @rram : that was bad from my part....got that corrected by editing my answer....please check if it is of help now...!! :)

Comment: Thanks. I think it occupied two rows now. One doubt, Can i use table inside table in newsletter is it a best practice? @Mr.Alien

Comment: @rram Yes you can, also make sure you use `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` and `border="0"` depends on requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

use single `<tr>` and 2 `<td>`'s to achieve this

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Zhg/23/)

Comment: Incorrect, you are changing the `display` behavior of the `td` element

Comment: @Mr.Alien : wanted to do in pure css....suggestions for trimming the `td` according to image dimension?? :)

Comment: Nope, I was going to suggest him to use `div` but stopped after I read he was making a *Newsletter*, so you shouldn't change the default behavior of the `td` element which is `display: table-cell;`

Comment: You wrapped everything in one row, how the logo went to the right side?

Comment: @rram : simple...1 `<tr>` having 2 `<td>`...1 for text, other having the image!! :)

Comment: Thanks +1 for your explanation. i understand that but what i was expecting is how there is less room for image and more room for text. I mean the image td width is less compared to text. how to do this? Is your `class:logo` making any sense here.

Comment: @rram : forgot to delete `class="logo"`, my bad...as for `td` width it depends on the content size, if not default....in my demo, if `img` is to take full width, you can check this fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/r5Zhg/24/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a extra `<td>` in the first row and use `rowspan="2"`

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Zhg/5/)

Answer (score 0):

if you ask me its better to apply width ALWAYS to td in newsletters, when i want to achieve spaces in newsletter (and work in outlook :P) i create empty tds with two spaces inside.

```
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

Check your edited JSfiddle

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Zhg/20/)

I hope I helped.